# Call function pointer using map

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, function-pointers

I am begginer in C++ and
I have the following template class:

```
template<typename... extensions>
class SomeServiceProxy
{
public:
void DoSomething() {std::cout<<"\ndoing sth\n";};
};
```

With the following pointer to function using "using" keyword

```
template<typename... extensions>
using DoSomethingFnPtr = void (SomeServiceProxy<extensions...>::*)();
```

And I am trying to put the method in a map and call it:

```
std::map<int, void*> myMap;



int main()
{
SomeServiceProxy<int> proxy;
DoSomethingFnPtr<int> memfnptr = &SomeServiceProxy<int>::DoSomething;
proxy.DoSomething();
(proxy.*memfnptr)(); //works
myMap[0]= &memfnptr;

auto it=myMap.find(0);
if(it != myMap.end() ){
SomeServiceProxy<int> proxy2;
(proxy2.&(it->second))(); //error
}



std::cout<<endl;
return 0;
}
```

What I get is : error: expected unqualified-id before ‘&’ token

Q: Is there any way to call the method using the map?

Comment: `myMap[0]= &memfnptr;` already makes no sense. You are not storing the member function pointer, you are storing a pointer to the member function pointer. In any case, if you are storing just a `void*` (or a member function pointer equivalent, since they cannot be cast to `void*`) with erased type in the map, then you need to cast it back to the original type before you can call it. How do you intend to use this map? Why is the type `void*`?

Comment: Most likely what you really want is a `std::map<int, std::function<void()>> myMap;` and then store `this`-capturing lambdas which call the member function in there. (But I am making some assumptions here. You should show the intended usage of the map.)

Comment: It's possible, but you need a cast and some more `*` and `()` sprinkled around: https://godbolt.org/z/f9vKGzjvx. Still, as user17732522 said, it doesn't make much sense to try that, you should show what are you trying to do instead of attempted solution.

Comment: as the error is not related to the `... extensions` and you arent using them I suggest to start without them. Once it works without extensions you can still add them back in

Comment: You need to convert it to the correct type and dereference properly; `(proxy2.*(*reinterpret_cast<DoSomethingFnPtr<int>*>(it->second)))()`. (You can tell from how incomprehensible that is that you're heading down a bad path to whatever it is that you want to accomplish.)

Comment: molbdnilos suggestion makes you code compile, but its not clear what you are trying to accomplish by first converting to `void*` and then back to the right type. To do this cast you need to know that the type is indeed `DoSomethingFnPtr<int>` and the cast is wrong when the type of the element in the map is something else.

Answer (score 1):

A `void*` is not a member function pointer. And `memfnptr` is a member function pointer, you should store it in the map rather than a pointer to it.

This is your code made to compile with the most obvious fixes:

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

template<typename... extensions>
class SomeServiceProxy
{
public:
void DoSomething() {std::cout<<"\ndoing sth\n";};
};

template<typename... extensions>
using DoSomethingFnPtr = void (SomeServiceProxy<extensions...>::*)();


std::map<int, DoSomethingFnPtr<int>> myMap;



int main()
{
    SomeServiceProxy<int> proxy;
    DoSomethingFnPtr<int> memfnptr = &SomeServiceProxy<int>::DoSomething;
    proxy.DoSomething();
    (proxy.*memfnptr)(); //works
    
    myMap[0]= memfnptr;

    auto it=myMap.find(0);
    if(it != myMap.end() ){
        SomeServiceProxy<int> proxy2;
        (proxy2.*(it->second))(); //error
    }
    std::cout<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I suppose you want to store member function pointers for different instantiations of `SomeServiceProxy` in the same map and thats why you used `void*`. There are much better ways to do type erasure than using `void*`, though what is more or less universal with type erasure is: Erasing the type is the easy part. The difficult part is to restore the type when you need it. When you store member function pointers for different instantiations of `SomeServiceProxy` in the same map then you can only call them when you know what instantiation of the template it is.

The simple solution is to use a `std::map<int, std::function<void()>>` then store lambdas (or some other functor) that encapsulates the instance and the member function to be called. For example:

```
std::map< int , std::function<void()>> mymap;
mymap[0] = []() { 
    SomeServiceProxy<int> proxy;
    proxy.DoSomething();
};
mymap[0]();
```